# syntax error, unexpected 'public' : laravel

Tags: laravel

Error is:

> FatalErrorException in PaymentController.php line 46:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

This error is showing when I'm trying to load the page. And I really don't know what is the problem here:

**PaymentController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Tzsk\Payu\Facade\Payment;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

public function pay() {
    /**
     * These are the minimum required fieldset.
     */
     $data = [
         'txnid' => strtoupper(str_random(8)), # Transaction ID.
         'amount' => rand(100, 999), # Amount to be charged.
         'productinfo' => "Product Information",
         'firstname' => "user", # Payee Name.
         'email' => "user@gmail.com", # Payee Email Address.
         'phone' => "9876543210", # Payee Phone Number.

          # Additional Fields With Data if any.
          # Optional Fields With Data if any.
     ];

     return Payment::make($data, function ($then) {
         //$then->redirectTo('/payment/status');
         # OR...
         //$then->redirectRoute('payment_status');
         # OR...
         $then->redirectAction('PaymentController@status');
         /**
          * Above are general Redirect::to(), Redirect::route() and  Redirect::action() Methods.
          * You can use them as you normally would (With Parameters if you  like) in any place to redirect.
          *
          * Note: You have to return the Payment Facade.
          */
     });
}
}

public function status() {
    $payment = Payment::capture(); # capture the payment after it's done. That's it.
    /**
     * $payment is the Model instance of payu_payment row.
     */
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two closing curly braces instead of one:

```
}
}
```

Remove one of those from the `pay()` method.